# The <today/> tag not working in my CAML Query?

Tags: web-part, visual-studio, sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query, caml-renderpattern

I am trying to retrieve the 5 most upcoming (with respect to expiry date) announcement list item "Title's".The query partly works but what it fails to do is include and display todays announcements as well (For ex: Announcements posted earlier in the morning).

I looked around the net and all of that suggests adding the `IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'` in the tag, but it still does not work.  What am I missing? I have also tried using the `<now/>`.

[image: Query]

[image]

Comment: This looks like it should work to me. I know this sounds like a stupid question, are you certain the data is there to supply the expected results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're sure that all the announcements you want has an Expire datetime then you're missing an "or+isnull" like this:

```
<Query>
 <Where>
  <And>
   <IsNotNull>
    <FieldRef Name="Title" />
   </IsNotNull>
   <Or>
    <IsNull>
     <FieldRef Name="Expires" />
    </IsNull>
    <Geq>
     <FieldRef Name="Expires" />
     <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">
      <Today />
     </Value>
    </Geq>
   </Or>
  </And>
 </Where>
 <OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name="Expires" Ascending="True" />
 </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried adding the <or> content, but it would still not display todays announcements. I have put up a screenshot for reference. I tried the <Now/> tag as well and it wouldnt work. Please advise.

Comment: Interesting observation. I tried the same query to retrieve calendar (event list) items and it displays just fine with the <today/> function. However it still does not display items that have expired an hour ago, which is good.

Answer (score 2):

Partly answered:

I just used the date and not the datetime. Since it was just announcements I didn't mind it being on the page for an extra day. The default expires field only holds the data value anyway. A simple `<geq>` on the Expires field with `type="Date"` did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I set up some announcements exactly like what you have in the screen shot. I did not get correct results in my view until I, for some reason, included the  Expires field in the ViewFields element.

```
<View Name="{5613B6A8-3D6D-40B0-9597-8CDBD9DD92AC}" Type="HTML" DisplayName="TodayOrLater" Url="/teams/root/it/Lists/Announcements/TodayOrLater.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/announce.png">
                <Query>
                    <Where>
                        <And>
                            <IsNotNull>
                                <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
                            </IsNotNull>
                            <Geq>
                                <FieldRef Name="Expires"/>
                                <Value Type="DateTime">
                                    <Today/>
                                </Value>
                            </Geq>
                        </And>
                    </Where>
                </Query>
                <ViewFields>
                    <FieldRef Name="Attachments"/>
                    <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/>
                    <FieldRef Name="Modified"/>
                    <FieldRef Name="Expires"/>
                </ViewFields>
                <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
                <Aggregations Value="Off"/>
                <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
            </View>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you show me your outpu to get a better picture please. And the paged=true property you have used is interesting. UNfortunately I cannot use it my query as it does not work for some reason. I have to specify spQuery.Rowlimit=5;

Comment: Just to be clear, that is the View Definition inside of a custom view page.

Comment: Hmmm....Robert I am trying to create a visual web part. Take a look at my output (added to original question) to see if me using the <view> tag makes sense please. Thanks