# How make [today] work in a programmatically created view filter?

Tags: csom, jsom, view

I am trying to write javascript CSOM code to programmatically create a StaleContent view on every document library in each of 50 site collections, rather than having to do it manually.

The filter condition I want to apply to the view is "Modified"; "is less than or equal to"; "[Today]-1005".  (translation: show me only documents with a modified date older than 2 years and 9 months). For testing purposes, instead of "[Today]-1005" I am using just "[Today]".

My code is successfully creating the StaleContent view and including the filter condition I want, but the view does not actually work until I edit the view in the browser and save it *without making any changes to it!!*

I'll post my entire code below for the benefit of anyone else trying to do something like this, but my question is: **does anyone know of a change I can make in my code so that the [Today] parameter in the filter gets recognized correctly without having to edit and resave the view in the browser?**

Code (the server url for the context is fake for privacy reasons, of course):

```
function runCode (){
  //get the context of the site
  var context = new SP.ClientContext('http://myserver.net/sites/wbt/SPS/MSP');

  // attach a onRequestFailed function to the client context.
  context.add_requestFailed(function (sender, args) {
      alert('Request failed: ' + args.get_message());
  });

  //get all the views for a specific list present on the site
  var viewCollection = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("TestDocs").get_views();  
  //context.load(viewCollection);    
  console.log("viewCollection size: " + Object.keys(viewCollection).length);
  //console.log(viewCollection);

  //  create a custom view ViewCreationInformation method. 
  //  set view title and fields to be shown on the view
  var createView = new SP.ViewCreationInformation();  
  createView.set_title("StaleContent");   
  var viewFields = ["Name","Modified", "Modified By"];  
  createView.set_viewFields(viewFields);

  //build query
  var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();  
  var query = "<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><Value Type='text'>[Today]-5</Value></Geq></Where>";  
  camlQuery.set_viewXml(query);  
  createView.set_query(camlQuery);

  //add view to the collection and execute the query
  viewCollection.add(createView);
  context.load(viewCollection);     

  context.executeQueryAsync(function (){
    var viewEnumerator = viewCollection.getEnumerator();
    var viewCount = 0;
    while (viewEnumerator.moveNext()){
      //debugger;
      var oview = viewEnumerator.get_current();
      var currView = oview.get_objectData().get_properties();
      console.log("Title:", currView.Title);
      viewCount ++;
      console.log("viewCount:",viewCount);
      if(currView.Title==="StaleContent")alert("StaleContent view successfully created.");
      } //end while
  }); //end QueryAsync function

} //end runCode function
```

Comment: Could you try ``Value Type='DateTime'``

Comment: As Danny suggested, I also think the Value Type should be 'DateTime'.  Have a look at this one also: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32351/the-today-tag-not-working-in-my-caml-query

Comment: I have tried 4 things, none of which works: 1. <Value Type='DateTime'>[Today]-5</Value>  Result: view must be re-saved in the browser to work. 2. <Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value> Result: View works in the browser without resaving BUT does not meet my needs. 3. <Value Type='DateTime'><Today-5 /></Value> Fail: did not put anything in the filter value 4.  <Value Type='DateTime'><Today />-5</Value> FAIL: inserts "-5" in the filter field, the view *appears* to work on opening the browser, but throws error when editing the view "Filter value is not in a supported date format". Ideas?

Comment: <Value Type='DateTime'><Today />-5</Value> also failed: inserts '-5' in filter field, throws save error when editing view.

Comment: Eureka! A friend suggested using the CAML builder to look at the CAML on the view, and this worked: <Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-1' /></Value>

Comment: You can now add your own Answer and refer to: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135968/what-is-the-difference-between-caml-offset-and-offsetdays

Answer (score 0):

Eureka! A friend suggested using the CAML builder to look at the CAML on the view, and this worked:

Many thanks to Trent McDonald for the suggestion of using a CAML builder to solve this.